# Split a column of values into its components

Tags: r

I have the following data frame (df) where for each participant, the column "grades" was built by pasting the scores on some items. So for example, the participant 'a' has obtained 4 on one item, 7 on another and 8 on a third one. Note that grades is now a character. Note also that participant 'b' has only two scores (let say this was a different exam from participant 'a').
What I need is a new column that will be the average of each score. So participant 'a' will have (4+7+8)/3 and participant 'b' will have (5+9)/2.

```
df = data.frame(participant = c('a', 'b'),
                grades= c('478', '58'),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here what I did

```
df$mean = sapply(df$grades, 
   FUN = function(x) strsplit(x, "") %>% .[[1]] %>% as.numeric %>% mean())
```

It works well, but it is not very readable and more importantly, it is slow (I have 100,000 rows, so it takes about half a minute and I need to do that several times). I wonder if someone has a better solution. Maybe in the tidyverse package or some other package.

Comment: *Not very readable* is a subjective statement. Omit all non-base R code (ie, less code, maybe *more readable*): `lapply(strsplit(df$grades, ""), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))`

Comment: You right. I forgot to add that it is also slow with a lot of data.

Comment: `rowMeans` or `colMeans` will be quite a bit faster than a separate `mean` call for each row. I'd `strsplit` into a matrix (filling out the lengths of shorter `grades`), and then use `rowMeans` or `colMeans` depending how you fill the matrix. You can use `sprintf` or `formatC` to pad the strings with whitespace before splitting.

Comment: With one million rows the instruction in @PoGibas comment took 12 seconds.